# Save variable after my app closes (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, variables, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to save a variable in Xcode so that it saves even after the app has closed, how ever when I access it I do it from a several different classes and files, and I change the value of the variable when I access it. Therefore similar threads do not completely apply, the value to be stored is a string and here is the code I have up until now:

```
var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(Token, forKey: "") as! String
```

I believe this is the correct format, but I don't know how to call it to change it because when I try I get an error message saying expected declaration.

Anyway any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: what the `as! String` for?

Comment: I though it was necessary to make it a string? I'm kind of new to swift to be honest

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all you have to specify an unique key to store the variable (in the example `MyKey` ).

In `AppDelegate > applicationDidFinishLaunching` register the key with a default value.
The benefit is you can use a non-optional variable and you have a defined default value.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let defaultValue = ["MyKey" : ""]
defaults.register(defaults: defaultValue)
```

Now you can from everywhere read the value for the key

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let token = defaults.string(forKey: "MyKey")
```

and save it

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(token, forKey: "MyKey")
```

Comment: Soooo, when ever I want to change the value? how should I?

Comment: read the value, change it and write it back from wherever you want. Normally the value is read in `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()` of a view controller into an instance variable. This instance variable can be changed and could be written back e.g. in `viewWillDisappear()` when the view controller will be left.

Comment: sooo  'let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let token = defaults.stringForKey(global.token)' being global token th new value?

Comment: exactly, but if you want to modify `token` use `var token`. Please read also the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH1-SW1

Comment: and how would I get the value back when the app is re opened

Comment: `defaults.stringForKey` **reads** the value, `defaults.setObject…` **writes** it. Just read it when or where you need it

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3**

(thanks to vadian's answer)

In `AppDelegate > applicationDidFinishLaunching` :

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let defaultValue = ["myKey" : ""]
    defaults.register(defaults: defaultValue)
```

to save a key:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set("someVariableOrString", forKey: "myKey")
defaults.synchronize()
```

to read a key:

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let token = defaults.string(forKey: "myKey")
```

Comment: You don't need `synchronize`. In fact, it can be a problem to force this. It's explained in the documentation and in many Questions and Answers. Example: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87314/68030

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a string variable called `token`

To save/update the stored value on the device:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(token, forKey: "mytoken")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

In the code above I made sure to give the key a value ("mytoken"). This is so that we later can find it.

To read the stored value from the device:

```
let token = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("mytoken") as? String
```

Since the method `objectForKey` returns an optional `AnyObject`, I'll make sure to cast it to an optional `String` (optional meaning that it's either nil or has a value).

Comment: Im adding this code to the Appdelegate,  and then when the value is changed Im adding both lines is that right?

Comment: You add both lines (setObject... and synchronize...) anywhere in your code when you want to save the token to the device, yes.

Comment: You don't need synchronize. In fact, it can be a problem to force this. It's explained in the documentation and in many Questions and Answers. Example: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87314/68030

Answer (score -4):

Add `default.synchronize()` after setting value.

Comment: how do I change the value, im sorry im absolutely lost here could you be more specific, like a bit more specific please?

Comment: Calling `synchronize()` is unnecessary. [See this explanation.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87314/79551)