# Swift 3 Xcode 8 Cannot use instance member

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to code a personal password-manager for me because other ones, I say weren't so nice to me... I´m using XCode 8 in Swift 3 and I´m trying to store my arrays (titles and passwords) in the NSUserDefaults, or in Swift3 UserDefaults. I made it like an other answer on an other question told me ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923410/save-variable-after-my-app-closes-swift/42313637#42313637?newreg=f97221a7f84f4b209799fc183f52c223)), but I am getting an error: 2 "Cannot use instance member "saves" within property initializer; property initializers run before "self" is available"-Errors... I don´t know how to fix this and I thought: Let´s ask. I know there are many questions how to fix this error, but I´m not really understanding the answers... (I´m new to coding...) My code to retrieve the value is this at the moment:

```
let saves = UserDefaults.standard
var titles = saves.array(forKey: "titlesSave")
//The XCode-Error is here...
var passwords = saves.array(forKey: "passwordsSave")
//...and here.
```

It isn´t in any function or special class, only the ViewController-Class. The only things I changed from the other question is that I´m using two instead of one var, I called the "container" for the "UserDefaults.standard" saves instead of defaults and I´m using arrays. If the error could be there (I don´t know it to be honestly), here my code from the AppDelegate.swift:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let saves = UserDefaults.standard
    let defaultTitles = ["titlesSave" : ["Bitte auswählen!"]]
    let defaultPasswords = ["passwordsSave" : ["Bitte auswählen!"]]
    saves.register(defaults: defaultTitles)
    saves.register(defaults: defaultPasswords)
    return true
}
```

I hope someone can help me. And, as told above, I know there are other questions to this error, but I can't understand what I have to change from them.

Comment: Put the code in a function.

Comment: defaultPasswords are overriding defaultTitles

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you! There are no more Errors!

Comment: @LeoDabus Can be true. I try this. If yes, have you got an Idea how to fix that? (I don´t know if this is as you said because I haven´t told the program to save the new arrays... I´ll do this now.)

Comment: Create a single dictionary

Comment: @LeoDabus How can I create 1 Dictionary for 2 Values? Sorry, but, as I said, I´m new to coding...

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried it now and it isn´t overriding. Everything works. Even if I restart the App, new created Items will be still there.

Comment: `["titlesSave": ["Bitte auswählen!"], "passwordsSave": ["Bitte auswählen!"]]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you! I will see if I need it or not...